# Get a clob output of a stored procedure over a dblink

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, dblink

I have a procedure that runs queries on a few tables and manipulates the output into a clob that it returns. I need to call this procedure in a remote Database over a dblink and get the clob value that the procedure returns. I know that we cannot access non-scalar data like clob over a dblink. I know that if the clob were in a table on the remote side, I could just create a global temp table and on the local side and do a insert into my local temp table with a select over the remote table. But in my case, the clob is a manipulated output of the procedure.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

On the remote database, create a **function** to wrap around the procedure and return the CLOB as its return value. Then create a **view** that selects from this function and exposes the CLOB as a column. You should be able to query that CLOB column through the view remotely over a database link. I know this can work as I pull CLOB data over dblinks thousands of times a day in utilities I wrote, though I do remember it taking a bit of trial-and-error to make it happy.

If you cannot get that to work, there are a number of other workarounds available. One involves a remote package presenting package-declared collection types which can be used by a remote function in that package to disassemble the CLOB into a collection of varchar2(32767) records, return that collection to the calling database, which then using remote reference @dblink to that remote package's types is able to reassemble a local CLOB from the collection contents. But this kind of heavy-handed workaround really shouldn't be necessary.

Lastly, I should at least mention that using CLOBs for structured data is not a good design choice. CLOBs should have only unstructured data, the kind that is meaningful only to humans (like log files, free-form notes, user-entered descriptions, etc..). It should never be used for combining multiple pieces of meaningful structured data that a program is meant to interpret and work with. There are many other constructs that would handle that better than a CLOB.

Comment: The first method sounds good to me. I will try that out. Point taken about the clob not being a good design choice. I can bring this up with the person who made the design choice and see if there is a better alternative.

Comment: Just a point of clarification, this will only work if the CLOB is stored in a table. If it's a temporary CLOB created in PL/SQL and doesn't actually exist in a table anywhere, this won't work.  You'd have to go to the package-method I outlined.

Answer (score 1):

I think that that CLOB is to be split into chunks of varchar2(4000) and stored into a temporary table with preserve rows, so that via that DB-link you will only select from that table that contains the chunks of the CLOB and a column that indicates their order. That would mean creating a procedure in that remote DB which calls the procedure generating the CLOB, then splits that CLOB into chunks and inserts them into the global temporary table.